# How to limit mysql query and also limit it by a timestamp?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, limit

How could I take a mysql query like this:

```
SELECT id,title,timestamp,upvotes,downvotes,views FROM {$table} ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

and based on the `timestamp` (which is a standard mysql timestamp)

make my mysql not only `LIMIT $start_from, 20` but in addition...

Limit by:

if it was made today
if it was made between today and a week ago
if it was made between today and a month ago

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT id, title, timestamp, upvotes, downvotes, views 
FROM {$table} 
WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY count 
DESC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

[MySQL Reference Manual `DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,title,timestamp,upvotes,downvotes,views 
FROM {$table} 
where timestamp >= now() - interval 1 week

SELECT id,title,timestamp,upvotes,downvotes,views 
FROM {$table} 
where timestamp >= now() - interval 1 month
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a where clause to check the timestamp for the range you want.